# How can I fit natural deduction trees nicely into enumerate?

Tags: enumerate, proof-package

Here's my code with `\usepackage{proof}`:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]

\item\infer[\to\text{\tiny\textbf{I}$_1$}]
{(A\land B)\to A}
{\infer[\land\text{\tiny\textbf{E}}]
    {A}
    {[A\land B]^1}
}   
\item \infer[\to\text{\tiny\textbf{I}$_1$}]
{(A\land B)\to A}
{\infer[\land\text{\tiny\textbf{E}}]
    {A}
    {[A\land B]^1}
}

\end{enumerate}
```

As you can see, the output isn't very presentable. I'd like the natural deduction trees to appear under the letters a,b,...etc.). Can this be done? What I've tried so far is use `\hbox{}` after `\item` and the trees on the next line. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  Note the different alignment styles for a) and b).

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]

\item\raisebox{-\height}% align baseline to top
{\infer[\to\text{\tiny\textbf{I}$_1$}]
{(A\land B)\to A}
{\infer[\land\text{\tiny\textbf{E}}]
    {A}
    {[A\land B]^1}
}}
\item\raisebox{\dimexpr\topskip-\height}% align top to top
{\infer[\to\text{\tiny\textbf{I}$_1$}]
{(A\land B)\to A}
{\infer[\land\text{\tiny\textbf{E}}]
    {A}
    {[A\land B]^1}
}}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
[![demo][1]][1]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, especially your first output. Thanks alot!